# seas start year error R

Tags: r, time-series

I am currently trying to deseasonalize data for ARIMA models using the U.S. Census Bureau's package seasonal
`install.packages("seasonal")`

you can find a modified version of the [data set here](https://slapadabias.wordpress.com/2015/05/20/deseasonlizeable/).

also there is a [vignette of the package here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seasonal/vignettes/seas.pdf) which gives very straight-forward directions as to how to install and specify X-13 so the seas command will run.

I've made sure that I installed X-13 properly, and indeed the program tells me "'seasonal' should work fine!" I've made sure the data is converted to the right format, but when I call the function I get an error.

The first observation in the time series is july first 1981, and the final being October first 2010.

`season0<-as.ts(seasonal,start=c(1981,7),end=c(2010,10),frequency=4,class='mts')`

which converts the earliest observation in the set to the number 4199. however, when I call the function
`seas(season0)` it spits out
`Error in seas(season0) : start year of 'x' must be > 999.`

I don't understand why this is the case since I checked that my installation was right and that may start year is way bigger than 999.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data has the value 4199, this means that you included the date column when trying to form your `ts` object. Since you specified the `start` and `frequency` of your time series in your `ts` function, you no longer need the date values as it will be generated by the function through its arguments.

I included the data here to make it easy for others to reproduce the example.

```
        seasonal<-structure(list(X1 = c(29768, 29860, 29952, 30042, 30133, 30225, 
30317, 30407, 30498, 30590, 30682, 30773, 30864, 30956, 31048, 
31138, 31229, 31321, 31413, 31503, 31594, 31686, 31778, 31868, 
31959, 32051, 32143, 32234, 32325, 32417, 32509, 32599, 32690, 
32782, 32874, 32964, 33055, 33147, 33239, 33329, 33420, 33512, 
33604, 33695, 33786, 33878, 33970, 34060, 34151, 34243, 34335, 
34425, 34516, 34608, 34700, 34790, 34881, 34973, 35065, 35156, 
35247, 35339, 35431, 35521, 35612, 35704, 35796, 35886, 35977, 
36069, 36161, 36251, 36342, 36434, 36526, 36617, 36708, 36800, 
36892, 36982, 37073, 37165, 37257, 37347, 37438, 37530, 37622, 
37712, 37803, 37895, 37987, 38078, 38169, 38261, 38353, 38443, 
38534, 38626, 38718, 38808, 38899, 38991, 39083, 39173, 39264, 
39356, 39448, 39539, 39630, 39722, 39814, 39904, 39995, 40087, 
40179, 40269, 40360, 40452), Employment.Cost.Index.BLS = c(38.2, 
39, 39.6, 40.1, 41, 41.5, 42.2, 42.7, 43.4, 43.9, 44.7, 45, 45.6, 
46.2, 46.8, 47.1, 47.8, 48.2, 48.7, 49, 49.6, 49.9, 50.3, 50.7, 
51.2, 51.7, 52.4, 52.9, 53.7, 54.2, 54.9, 55.5, 56.4, 56.9, 57.9, 
58.5, 59.3, 59.7, 60.5, 61.2, 61.9, 62.3, 63, 63.4, 64, 64.4, 
65.2, 65.6, 66.3, 66.7, 67.3, 67.8, 68.4, 68.7, 69.3, 69.7, 70.3, 
70.6, 71.2, 71.7, 72.3, 72.6, 73.3, 73.7, 74.4, 75, 75.6, 76.2, 
77.1, 77.6, 77.9, 78.7, 79.5, 80.2, 81.3, 82.1, 83, 83.6, 84.6, 
85.3, 86.3, 87, 87.9, 88.7, 89.5, 90, 91.3, 92, 93, 93.5, 94.7, 
95.6, 96.5, 96.9, 98, 98.6, 99.5, 100, 100.7, 101.6, 102.7, 103.3, 
104.2, 105, 106.1, 106.7, 107.6, 108.3, 109.2, 109.5, 110, 110.1, 
110.2, 110.4, 111.6, 112.1, 112.3, 112.7), Import.Price.Index.IMF = c(78.037, 
77.3249, 79.3683, 77.7893, 76.876, 76.5819, 75.4982, 74.2598, 
74.3682, 74.9564, 75.5137, 76.3497, 76.3497, 76.1175, 74.3372, 
73.9347, 73.7954, 74.7242, 73.0523, 70.8231, 70.6838, 72.5415, 
73.5941, 75.8852, 78.7182, 78.6098, 78.9847, 81.0669, 80.0258, 
81.6222, 82.8021, 83.6812, 82.0849, 82.8946, 84.1671, 82.9409, 
85.3007, 89.789, 86.9433, 85.0231, 84.7223, 85.7403, 85.4307, 
85.5822, 86.946, 86.9763, 85.8247, 86.7338, 85.8853, 85.7035, 
85.2792, 86.8248, 88.4916, 89.3401, 90.3099, 92.1585, 91.7342, 
91.5221, 92.0676, 92.4312, 91.8554, 93.0677, 91.9464, 89.825, 
89.4916, 89.0674, 86.3702, 85.0671, 83.7942, 83.37, 83.0366, 
84.37, 86.1883, 87.9158, 90.128, 90.1583, 91.5827, 91.7948, 90.522, 
88.9158, 87.2793, 84.067, 83.6427, 85.7035, 86.3096, 86.4611, 
89.2492, 87.1278, 87.7642, 88.0673, 90.4917, 92.1282, 93.8859, 
95.5527, 96.3406, 98.7651, 102.129, 102.765, 102.796, 105.947, 
107.038, 103.705, 104.159, 107.917, 110.433, 114.675, 118.857, 
128.495, 129.798, 110.342, 102.917, 106.554, 109.614, 112.372, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("X1", "Employment.Cost.Index.BLS", 
"Import.Price.Index.IMF"), row.names = c(NA, 118L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data above are imported from an excel sheet and the date values are not modified as they will be ignored in the following code:

```
season0<-ts(seasonal[,-1],frequency=4,start=c(1981,3))# no need to the `end` argument here, `start` and `frequency` are enough. N. 3 in the `start` argument refers to the third quarter of the year (date starts at 01-07-1981).
season0.seas<-seas(season0) # this will be run without error (have a look at season0 data to see the structure). 
plot(season0.seas) # and the plot.
```

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm. I knew it was some mundane detail like that. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a follow up question in regard to this data. When I try to execute the `final(season0.seas)` it only spits out the deseaonalized vector for employment, and the `inspect(season0.seas)` returns another error `Error in read.table(text = z0, colClasses = "numeric") : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
Error in read.table(text = z0, colClasses = "numeric") : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed`... I know this is a pretty rudimentary issue, but since I'll likely be working with a lot of time series it would be nice to know how to get this widely used package to work.

Comment: never mind it was because of R Studio that it was being grumpy.